# How to initialize dragula again after modifying my view

Tags: javascript, jquery, dragula

I use this code to initialize dragula when the page loads. After I modify my view with dragging and dropping a small container into another container, the small container does not have the functionality I specified in my dragula. Only after refreshing the webpage, the small container functionality is normal. How should I make my dragula work fine after modifying the view without the need to refresh the webpage?

```
<pre>
var drake = dragula(querySelectorAllArray('.Container'), {
    copy: function(el, source) {
       ......
}

</pre>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can nest the containers. You could possibly try calling a new instance for the second container, giving it a different class, e.g. `var drake2 = dragula(document.querySelector('.drake2'), {...});`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the dragula object as a global variable, and then destroy and rebind dragula after you have updated your view / container.

```
var drake =  window.dragula();

function setupDragula(){
    drake.destroy();
    drake = dragula([leftContainer, rightContainer]);
}
```